# PHP using array(?) to concatenate argument string?

Tags: php, string, concatenation

Sorry for not using the right terminology, but given how basic my PHP level is, perhaps you will not mind so much.

A function for a plugin I am using allows arguments in order to selectively echo content:

```
<?php phpquote(argumentstring); ?>
```

An example of the argument string is e.g.  **auto_refresh=0&tags=a,b,c**

I had always assumed it would be possible to use an array to build up a 'string' e.g. something like

```
<?php $arg=array( 'auto_refresh' => '0', 'tags' => 'a,b,c' );
phpquote($arg); ?>
```

And was therefore thinking I could bring in other content from another field e.g.

```
<?php 
$fieldcontent = get_field("field_content");
$arg=array( 'auto_refresh' => '0', 'tags' => $fieldcontent );
phpquote($arg); ?>
```

However, this does not seem to work and so my two questions are:

1. Is it possible to use an array to **build** such an argument string? Or does this depend on the plugin?
2. If so, is it possible to bring in content from elsewhere as the example above?

Thanks in advance. I appreciate this may seem like a really basic question with incorrect terminology (sorry!) so hope it makes sense to the experts.

Comment: What's the input? And what should be the output?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [`implode()`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.implode.php) and [`array_map()`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-map.php) PHP functions to make an array to become an argument string:

```
<?php

    $args = array( 'auto_refresh' => '0', 'tags' => 'a,b,c' );

    function rb_map( $a, $b ) {
        return $a . '=' . $b;
    }

    $arg_string = implode('&', array_map( 'rb_map', array_keys($args), $args ) );
    //var_dump($arg_string);
?>
```

Answer (score 2):

Loop through the array and use the `implode()` function for glueing pieces together.
[manual](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.implode.php)

Or you can do something like this, too:

```
$argumentString= "";
foreach($arg as $k=>$v){
    $argumentString.= $k.'='.$v.'&';
}
$argumentString = substr($argumentString,0,-1); //removes the last &
```

Comment: i like your answer, though I guess it would be nice if you could write up the code in a way that it fits the code used by the OP...

Comment: what do you think about this? [http://3v4l.org/BThWI](http://3v4l.org/BThWI)... feel free to use it in your answer ;)

Comment: To: RápliAndrás and @webeno: Thank you both so much for your replies :) Although I did end up using the implode and array_map method suggested by rambu, I can confirm that this works as well.

Answer (score 2):

```
<?php
$arg=array( 'auto_refresh' => '0', 'tags' => 'a,b,c' );
echo urldecode(http_build_query($arg)); //output: auto_refresh=0&tags=a,b,c
?>
```

Is this what you want?

Check [http_build_query](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.http-build-query.php) for more information

Comment: Thanks very much Dikesh for your help. I found this worked really well for me too, even though I ended up using one of the other methods in the end.  My final one was `$completearg = urldecode(http_build_query($arg));` and then `phpquote($completearg);`  I have upvoted it for others to read through as it seems like a really useful function!

Answer (score 1):

Whether or not you can use an array as the argument of a function depends on how that is defined / used in the function itself.

Consider this for example:

```
function test($var) {
    print_r($var);
}

$bla = array(1 => "test me", 2 => "balbla");

test($bla);
```

(You can play with it **[here](http://3v4l.org/IoQXp)**)

You can pass either a string or an array as an argument of the `test` function as `print_r` is able to handle both. If the function had `echo` for example, and you passed an array to the function as argument, it would fail.

Comment: Thanks webeno :)  your explanation really helped here even though did end up using code above I have upvoted your answer.